Crear un script en loop/bucle (.bat) en Windows95/98
En realidad lo que quiero hacer, es simplemente lanzar una aplicación con un script, y que al cerrarla, cierre el Windows.
En los Windows modernos, al menos, cuando creo un fichero por lotes con scripts .bat, hasta que no termina la ejecución de un programa, no salta al siguiente, pero en Windows 95 (en una máquina virtual), o me estoy perdiendo algo, o no pasa así, lanzo el script y automáticamente lanza la orden de cerrar todo.
Pensé por tanto en hacer un bucle, que compruebe que la aplicación se está ejecutando cada X (2 o 5 segundos por ejemplo con un timeout), pero no me reconoce los comandos como Tasklist.
Mi idea, era hacer, grosso modo, algo tan sencillo como esto:
@echo off

:Loop
tasklist | findstr "wordpad.exe"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (goto Loop) ELSE (goto End)

timeout 1 > nul

:End

rundll user.exe,ExitWindows

exit

Alguna forma de hacer algo similar en Windows 95/98? (rundll user.exe,ExitWindows, es obviamente, para que cierre el Widnows 95, en este caso)
En los Windows modernos, con cosas parecidas funciona perfectamente, y haciendo un prueba con el Wordpad, funciona sin problemas y sale del bucle al cerrar el Wordpad.

Un saludo.

Esto en Windows 98 funciona, supongo que en 95 funciona también, aunque, puede que cambie los comandos.
"start /wait" se pausa en la aplicación y al terminar pasa a la siguiente línea.
@ECHO OFF

START /WAIT "D:\Directorio\Programa.EXE"


ECHO Windows se cerrará en 3 segundos.
ECHO Ctrl+C para cancelar.
PING localhost -n 4 >nul

REM ECHO Presione cualquier tecla para cerrar Windows.
REM ECHO Ctrl+C para cancelar.
REM PAUSE>nul

REM RUNDLL32.EXE USER.EXE,ExitWindows

CLS

@EXIT

Otras maneras de apagar Windows, por si no te funciona esa...
RUNDLL32 KRNL386.EXE,exitkernel
(will also power down ATX boards)

RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,SHExitWindowsEx #
* -1 = Reload Shell
* 0 = Logoff 
* 1 = Shutdown
* 2 = Reboot 
* 4 = Forced Shutdown (unsafe: may generate data loss!)
* 5 = Exit To DOS 
* 8 = Poweroff 



Shut down : c:\windows\rundll.exe user.exe,ExitWindows 
Shut down : c:\windows\rundll.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx 5
Log-off   : c:\windows\rundll.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx
Restart   : c:\windows\rundll.exe user.exe,ExitWindowsExec
Reboot    : c:\windows\rundll.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx 2


en windows 95 puede que sea "start /w"

Bienvenido. Puedes editar la publicación si lo crees necesario. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conseguir tu primera medalla
